# Disable sending emails in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is there an easy way to disable sending mails in asp.net? I'm working with webforms but I do not want to send emails  while working in my development server. I could comment out every place my system sends an email, but I think there is an easier way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Check if the url contains 'test' or 'dev' or whatever your environment is called....? Just off the top of my head. For example: `if (!Request.Url.ToString().Contains("devEnvironment")) { //send email }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully you centralized your "send email" function. Then it is easy. Check if you are local/debug:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal || HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

And respond appropriately.

I choose to actually send the email, but I change the `to` to my email account and add an extra message about who the `to`, `cc`, and `bcc` in the message were (and ensure you clear all those fields out so no real email is sent). That way you can tell if your send email is working as expected -- especially if you are switching out templates, replacing data in the email, etc.

If you didn't centralize your "send email" functions... it may be time to bite the bullet and do it.

Comment: There is no "send mail" function. My department just got this VB code and we will be in charge of maintaining it now. I converted it to C# (we don't do VB) and there are send mail requests all over the place. I can't modify the code (add/remove/factorize functions) before the new C# code is tested. Thanks, I'll certralize my function as soon as I can !

Comment: Can you use something like `#if !DEBUG` then?

Comment: So like 30 seconds of copy/paste ? :)

Comment: yup, and 20 tons of nasty code : ( ill do that anyways, thanks!

Comment: Yeah I've been there. Inheriting crappy code is never fun. But I guess you were going to have to wrestle this monkey one day. Good luck sorting it out.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the easiest way to handle this is in the email configuration piece.  Usually it's either a database or web.config setting.  What you are looking for is the part that defines the name of the mail server to use for sending messages out.

Comment: if you change the email server string and it's expecting to relay off a mail server, the app will bomb when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Syn123: Well, considering there are a host of other issues in the very likely event that a mail server can't be found, the app should have appropriate error handling to be able to continue functioning when this occurs.

Comment: I'd have to agree, checking the availability of the mail is the best practice approach here, you can even block the mail port on the workstation's firewall at that point to stop the app from sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you're trying to do involves a little bit of architecture:

All the email addresses that the app sends to should be variables in your web.config, at which point it becomes easy to duplicate and comment out the email address string lines and set all the emails to go to you.

Otherwise, you have to either comment out where the email's sending from line by line which across many files becomes very error prone when you push into prod, or your app will time out when it's expecting to send an email while your testing.

You can also use properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: That'd be an interesting approach. My site can send to 500,000+ users.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend:

1. Use configSource for environment dependent settings (e.g. have a App_Data\config\dev and App_Data\config\live, etc).
2. In you dev config file just have an empty SMTP setting, as in -

The emails won't be sent, and no exception thrown (at least 4.5.2 of the .NET framework, which is what I'm using.

Hope this helps.