# Is there a way to prevent an ASP.NET Core app from sending any e-mails?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, smtp

I am a JR dev and I have an inherited a very fractured application that sends e-mail alerts for a lot of different events. I need to stop these alerts from going out temporarily.

Unfortunately the code is very dispersed and I can't comb through it all to find every piece of code that sends an e-mail. There's many functions that send e-mails. There's no central sendEmail function that's called through the application.

Is there a way stop SMTP for the whole application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could go about this. 
But it is difficult to diagnose without source code or some kind of guidance.

Solutions:

1. Simply look into the SMTP settings and leave them blank or comment them out
2. Search for a centralized send function somewhere in the application (provided it exists)
3. Look into whether or not your application has an SMTP service ex. SendGrid.

Although if this is to be a temporary solution, I would advocate using try/catch blocks to find which emails 
yield success later down the line. Logging success metrics will allow you to document and understand the application better.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions

Additional info:
[Disable sending emails in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163473/disable-sending-emails-in-asp-net)